# Commutative property of complex linear map and holomorphic function

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Suppose holomorphic functions $f,g,I\colon D \to D$ and path $a\colon [-\epsilon,\epsilon]\to D$ hold properties: $f(0)=g(0)=0=a(0)$ and $I(z)= i\cdot z$.

I'm working with following equation (the context is: Complex structure is independent of the chart):
$$
( f\circ g^{-1}\circ I\circ g\circ a )'(0)
=( f\circ g^{-1} )'(I\circ g\circ a(0))
\cdot (I\circ g\circ a)'(0)
$$
$$=( f\circ g^{-1})'( g\circ a(0))
\cdot I'( g\circ a(0))
\cdot ( g\circ a)'(0)
$$
$$=( f\circ g^{-1})'( g\circ a(0))
\cdot i
\cdot ( g\circ a)'(0)
$$
$$
=i
\cdot ( f\circ g^{-1}\circ  g\circ a)'(0)
$$
$$
=i
\cdot( f\circ a)'(0)
$$

My supervisor insists that I justify this by explaining ''Derivate of holomorphic function is complex linear so it commutes with $i$''. I'm not entirely sure if I should use it on equality between 3rd and 4th line or I could reduce the continued equality a step or two. I suppose you could consider 3rd line as product of two or three linear mappings and a vector but I see 3 complex numbers. So could you tell me where I'm using the property since I only see complex numbers past certain point or should I somehow skip some of this with the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines 3 to 4 use complex linearity. Note that the repeated use of $\circ$ makes it very difficult to read. Out of interest, are you looking at manifolds or Riemann surfaces?

Comment: How would you suggest to write those equations? PM me if you see it fit. I'm looking at Riemann surfaces.